References and Explanations for Hugh Woodin "On the Mathematical Necessity of the Infinite", Finite Peano Arithmetic (FPA)
In this lecture (I will only ask about the first 20 minutes), Woodin makes several interesting statements, that I would like more explanation on.

@6:08, Woodin outlines the axioms of FPA (the axioms of Finite Peano Arithmetic), and discusses the Induction Axiom vs. the Pigeonhole Principle, and how the former is weaker than the latter (or rather, it is not known whether or not they are equivalent).


Question1: Is there a reference (introductory textbook) for FPA, and these remarks about Induction vs. Pigeonhole?
Googling things likes "finite number theory axioms fpa" doesn't bring up many results, besides things like http://dcproof.com/FiniteArithmeticBlog.html, or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120150/can-fpa-really-prove-its-consistency


@7:44 Woodin says one can define $z=x^y$ in FPA ("takes a little work"), and hence FLT (Fermat's last theorem) can be written in FPA. Woodin goes on to claim that "Most (if not all) of the famous open problems in number theory can be refined to problems in FPA".


Question2: Is there a reference (introductory textbook) for these remarks, on converting known problems in number theory to questions in FPA?


@15:30, Woodin introduces a formula $\Phi_{PH}(x):=$ [$\exists y$ s.t. $y=PH_x$ and $2^{2^y}$ exists] (where $PH_x$ refers to the Paris-Harrington numbers), and a (almost) Godel sentence $\Theta_G$ in the language of FPA that expresses: [there is a proof of $(\neg \Theta_G)$ from FPA of length $<PH_{10}$, AND $PH_{100}$ exists], and he says that PA can prove that "there is a proof of $(\neg \Theta_G)$ from FPA of length $<PH_{11}$".
So if we believe PA is sound, then we believe that $\neg \Theta_G$ is true, i.e. EITHER all proofs of $(\neg\Theta_G)$ in FPA are longer $\geq PH_{10}$, OR $PH_{100}$ does not exist. But PA does show (see e.g. page 2 of this paper by Erdos) that PA does show that any fixed/individual Paris-Harrington number does exist, I think ($\color{red}?$). So if we believe PA is sound, then we believe that $(\neg \Theta_G)$ is true and all its proofs in FPA are longer $\geq PH_{10}$.
@18:00, Woodin says [FPA + $PH_{50}$] is not strong enough to tell us that all proofs of $(\neg \Theta_G)$ in FPA are longer $\geq PH_{10}$.



I'm just generally a bit lost at this last section (what is taking place in PA? What is taking place in FPA? If FPA proves something, it must be true in all models, and there are some very trivial models of FPA like $\{0\}$, so what can FPA even prove?);
...if someone could explain the point that Woodin is trying to make, in their own words, maybe I could understand better.



Question 4: also could one use the Goodstein function in place of the Paris-Harrington function, in the above analysis/point that Woodin is trying to make? I think so, but better to have someone confirm.


Re: question 3, note that lots of things are true in ${0}$. In particular, every statement of the form "$A\ge B$" is true there.
